# SQLite Duplicate column name

Tags: python, database, sqlite, duplicates

I am trying some hands on with SQLite integrated with Python and am trying to insert values into the DB via a .csv file. I am getting the error: DUPLICATE COLUMN NAME : Measure. I think this is happening because two columns are starting with the same name. Any leads on where I am going wrong?

[image]

```
for row in reader:
    if header:
        header = False
            sql_query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %s" % tablename
            cursor.execute(sql_query)

            sql_query = "CREATE TABLE %s (%s)" % (tablename,
                                                      ", ".join([ "%s TEXT" % col for col in row]))
            cursor.execute(sql_query)
```

TRACEBACK ERROR:

```
File "C:\Users\Rachit-PC\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda3\lib\site-
    packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 2881, in run_code
        exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
      File "<ipython-input-107-6337a434d788>", line 32, in <module>
        cursor.execute(sql_query)
    sqlite3.OperationalError: duplicate column name: Measure
```

Comment: `[ "%s TEXT" % col.replace(' ','_') for col in row]` could work, but the design is weak wih SQL injections

Comment: Look at the *actual* SQL being sent over.. don't guess.

Comment: @PRMoureu it says sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error
not sure what you meant by that.

Comment: My guess is that somehow only the first word is making it in there.  In any case, _don't_ put whitespace into your column names.  Why?  Because forever you will have to escape those names, and that's a big hassle you don't want if you can avoid it.

Comment: i'm not sure why you have this error now, as said above, you should remove spaces in column names,  that's the purpose of the given code. Maybe check how the `header` is defined in your code ? And `print(sql_query)` before execute it

Comment: @PRMoureu This is the output to my print(sql_query)                
 Out[119]: 'CREATE TABLE va_ipshep_apr2017cms_09mar17 (Provider ID TEXT, Hospital Name TEXT, Address TEXT, City TEXT, State TEXT, Zip TEXT, County Name TEXT, Phone Number TEXT, Measure ID TEXT, Measure Name TEXT, Survey Question TEXT, Answer Description TEXT, Answer Percent TEXT, Number Item Responses TEXT, Footnote TEXT, Measure Start Date TEXT, Measure End Date TEXT)'

Answer (score 2):

```sql
CREATE TABLE va_ipshep_apr2017cms_09mar17 (
    Provider ID TEXT,
    Hospital Name TEXT,
    ...
```

The first column has the name `Provider`, and the type `ID TEXT`.
The second column has the name `Hospital`, and the type `Name TEXT`.

If you want to have special characters in the column names, you have to [quote](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) them:

```sql
CREATE TABLE va_ipshep_apr2017cms_09mar17 (
    "Provider ID" TEXT,
    "Hospital Name" TEXT,
    ...
```